# Does IE10 (Edge) support msRequestFullScreen?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

When I try to use the following functions in Microsoft Edge, they are invalid and I'm not sure why. Is it not supported by IE10 (Edge)? Here's my code:

For `requestFullScreen`:

```
/*
 * fullScreen
 */
function fullScreen(ele){
  ele.msRequestFullScreen();
}
```

For `exitFullScreen`:

```
/*
 * exitFullScreen
 */
function exitFullScreen(ele){
   if (document.msExitFullScreen) {
     document.msExitFullScreen();
   } else if (document.msCancelFullScreen) {
     document.msCancelFullScreen();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254939(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **IE Version**
>
> Microsoft Edge and beyond
>
> **Recommended Usage**
>
> `requestFullscreen`

And:

> In IE11 and Microsoft Edge, you can prevent untrusted content from opening in full-screen mode. **To do so, you must call `requestFullscreen`** from a user-initiated event, such as a button click, rather than automatically from script. (Emphasis Added)

In Edge and beyond, use `requestFullScreen` instead of `msRequestFullScreen`:

```
function fullScreen(ele){
  ele.requestFullScreen();
}
```

The same goes for [`exitFullScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254936(v=vs.85).aspx) and `cancelFullScreen`. Learn more about the fullscreen API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx).